# Decompilation error for IDA8.3 lumina SERVER

Tags: decompiling, ida

lumina: connect: connection failed because the destination computer denied the connection.
142089810: cloud: Server is not available

I cleaned up the registry and reinstalled it.

Does anyone know about this problem?
I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: I have the same issue